# Can I create a library like a cocoapod or framework file for iOS or an aar file or gradle dependency for Android with Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a library our partners use to drop our UI and flow into their apps. Can I make a cocoapod or framework file or an aar file or gradle dependency with a flutter project?

Comment: You mean native apps calling flutter ?

Comment: Potentially, yes. Right now we give our partners a framework file for iOS and an aar file for Android. The partners drop these files in their project and when they call to init our SDK, our sdk will open and show our UI and flow. Is there an easy way to distribute something similar with a project written with Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! For general information, see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app

1. To create an AAR from a Flutter module that other Android apps can use without any direct dependency on Flutter, see [Option A - Depend on the Android Archive (AAR)](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup#option-a---depend-on-the-android-archive-aar)
2. To create a Framework from a Flutter module that other iOS apps can use without any direct dependency on Flutter, see [Option B - Embed frameworks in Xcode](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup#option-b---embed-frameworks-in-xcode)

You can also find samples at
https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/master/experimental/add_to_app, refer to the respective samples: `android_using_prebuilt_module` and `ios_using_prebuilt_module`

Now, if you are talking about integrating Flutter into an existing library (AAR or Framwork), then no, this is currently not supported, but is being explored:

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39027
- note that this would be termed “add-to-library” as opposed to "add-to-app"
- also mentioned, [flutter/add-to-app](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app):

  > Packing a *Flutter library into another sharable library* or packing multiple Flutter libraries into an application isn’t supported.